# How to convert "pointer to pointer type" to const?

Tags: c++, constants, const-cast

With the following code

```
void TestF(const double ** testv){;}
void callTest(){
    double** test;
    TestF(test);
}
```

I get this:

```
'TestF' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'double **' to 'const double **'
```

I cannot understand why. 
Why `test` cannot be silently casted to `const double**`?
Why should I do it explicitly? I know that

```
TestF(const_cast<const double**>(test))
```

makes my code correct, but I feel this should be unnecessary.

Are there some key concepts about *const* that I'm missing?

Comment: The issue has been covered many times here, but here's a FAQ entry dedicated to this very question http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const

Comment: possible duplicate of [constness and pointers to pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441979/constness-and-pointers-to-pointers)

Comment: There is **no cast** in the first block of code. There is an **implicit conversion**, and the various answers explain why that **conversion** is not legal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The language allows implicit conversion from `double **` to `const double *const *`, but not to `const double **`. The conversion you attempt would implicitly violate the rules of const correctness, even though it is not immediately obvious.

The example in the [de-facto standard] C++ FAQ illustrates the issue

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion

Basically, the rule is: once you add `const` at some level of indirection, you have to add `const` to all levels of indirection all the way to the right. For example, `int *****` cannot be implicitly converted to `int **const ***`, but it can be implicitly converted to `int **const *const *const *`

Comment: "All the way to the right" except for the last one?

Answer (score 11):

It is correct that a `double **` cannot be implicitly converted to a `const double **`. It can be converted to a `const double * const *`, though.

Imagine this scenario:

```
const double cd = 7.0;
double d = 4.0;
double *pd = &d;
double **ppd = &pd;
const double **ppCd = ppd;  //this is illegal, but if it were possible:
*ppCd = &cd;  //now *ppCd, which is also *ppd, which is pd, points to cd
*pd = 3.14; // pd now points to cd and thus modifies a const value!
```

So, if your function does not intend to modify any of the pointers involved, change it to take a `const double * const *`. If it intends to do modifications, you must decide whether all the modifications it does are safe and thus `const_cast` can be used, or whether you really need to pass in a `const double **`.