# Can't (implicitly) convert from char** to const char**?

Tags: c++

E.g. the following will fail to compile:

```
auto foo = [](const char**) {};
char* ptr = nullptr;
foo(&ptr);
```

Visual studio says that there's a conversion that loses qualifiers. Clang says `cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const char **' with an rvalue of type 'char **`". Perhaps my brain just isn't working today, but why is this dis-allowed? `char*` can implicitly convert to `const char*` after all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910296/how-to-convert-pointer-to-pointer-type-to-const

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait, yes my brain isn't working today. `foo` can assign a `const char*` to the pointer, which is clearly bad.