# How to create 'char *[]' in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to call into a C library from C++. The interface requires `char* []`. The compilation fails if I pass `const char * []`.

How do I safely create one of these?
This is the best I can do, but I don't know if it's even correct. I'm creating the array with 1 c-string in it only.

```
string attr = "memberUid";
vector<char> attr_v(attr.begin(), attr.end());
attr_v.push_back('\0');
char * attrs[] = {&attr_v[0]};
```

I do not want to trigger the deprecated conversion warning, i.e. the one that fires with the following:

```
char * attr = "memberUid";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [constness and pointers to pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441979/constness-and-pointers-to-pointers) … note that `char *[]` as a function parameter is a synonym for `char **`.

Comment: `char attr[] = "memberUid"; char *attrs[] = { attr };`

Comment: WhozCraig, that works, why does char * attr = "memberUid" count as a deprecated conversion but char attr[] does not? Aren't they both just setting a char array buffer?

Comment: Does the C function you're trying to call modify the strings you pass to it? If so, WhozCraig's comment looks good to me. If not, I'd use an explicit cast from a string literal to `char *`.

Comment: @RodrigoSalazar No, `char *attr = "memberUid";` means something roughly like `static const char __special_variable[] = "memberUid"; char *attr = (char *) __special_variable;`, which is why it is unsafe, and why it is deprecated.

Comment: BTW, OP's solution works.

Comment: @Jarod42 OP's solution doesn't work, because `&attr_v[0]` has type `char*`, and is not an array.  And `char* attrs[]` is only legal as a function argument, where it is the same as `char**`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: OP's code **is** correct : https://ideone.com/gts7oc

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah yes.  I'd missed the curly braces.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a vector of strings
(`std::vector<std::string>`), which I'll call `source`:

```
std::vector<char*> asArgument( source.size() );
std::transform(
    source.begin(), source.end(),
    asArgument.begin(),
    []( std::string const& elem ) { return const_cast<char*>( elem.c_str() ); } );
cFunction( asArgument.data(), asArgument.size() );
```

If you need the array of `char*` to be `NULL` terminated, just
create `asArgument` with `source.size() + 1`.

Of course, if you need string literals:

```
char const* asArgument[] = { ... };
```

will do the trick, with a `const_cast` at the call site
(`const_cast<char**>( asArgument )`).

This assumes that the called function doesn't actually try to
modify anything; that the absence of `const` is only because it
is legacy code.  If it does modify any of the strings passed to
it, you'll have to make deep copies.

Comment: +1 fir reasonable answer. nit: i would support more compilers by explicitly specifying the result type of the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help , for loop is need to init the whole array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<string> attr_v;
  attr_v.push_back("10");
  char * attr[100];
  attr[0]= const_cast<char*>(attr_v[0].c_str()); 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: A loop, or `std::transform`.